# How to HATEOAS when API returns Long?

Tags: spring-hateoas

I would like to use HATEOAS in a Spring-boot @RestController; the method looks like

```java
@GetMapping("/{transactionId}")
public UUID search(@PathVariable String transactionId){
    ...
    return o.getUID();
}
```

How can I inject the "_links" structure?

Comment: I wonder why vote -1 without leaving any comment at all